# How do I get more than 2 threads to execute with Surefire + Maven?

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I can't get any more than two threads executing at once using the Maven + Surefire combo. I've experimented with a number of combinations of threadCount, perCoreThreadCount, and useUnlimitedThreads settings, but can never do better than two threads. See attached screenshot: there will be ~12 Firefox windows, but only two "driving" at one time.

[image]

My machine has 4 cores of 2.6 Ghz i7 in it, so it's not like I should be hitting a hardware limit yet.

Here's an example of one of the Surefire configurations:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test*.*</include>
                </includes>
                <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

For my tests, I'm using Scala wrapped in a JUnit runner. Each test is in its own class. My JUnit is 4.10, Maven 3.04 I think.

Comment: I don't think those options work on `2.7.2` of Surefire. Have you tried switching to the latest version?

Comment: What's the latest version? It seems our team is moving toward using ScalaTest runner, which has more effective (in our testing) parallel support.

Comment: The latest version is always in the top RHS of the [plugin site][1]. Ie `2.12.4` [1]: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: Please follow-up, Aaron; otherwise the question remains useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define MAVEN_OPTS=-Dmaven.artifact.threads=10 into Maven environment variable.

Or use the parameter "-T" when you execute mvn.

Examples:

mvn -T 4 clean install # Builds with 4 threads

mvn -T 1C clean install # 1 thread per cpu core

mvn -T 1.5C clean install # 1.5 thread per cpu core

See that you can specify the numbers of threads or even the number of cores, since you are using Maven 3.x.

For more detailed information, take a look at this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I had a similar problem. Turns out I was trying to run test classes from different JUnit categories, but set parallel to *classes*.

The classes in each category were indeed executed in parallel, but the categories were executed serially.

I ended up updating my failsafe configuration to

```
<configuration>
    <parallel>suitesAndClasses</parallel>                        
    <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
   <threadCountClasses>4</threadCountClasses>
</configuration>
```